# Hello world example for dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a lot of variability in what Google pulls up and none of it seems to distill the basics very well.

Can someone provide a "hello world" example of JavaScript dependency injection.

I've used DI in PHP but with out the simple class-object paradigm, I'm finding it difficult to get a grasp of how this would function in JavaScript.

A hello world example of the method angular.js uses would be best, and why it uses `toString()` if it is not too complex would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found this blog entry to be helpful when looking at DI with JavaScript:
http://merrickchristensen.com/articles/javascript-dependency-injection.html

Comment: I didn't find it useful b.c. the example was pretty big for a 'hello world' type example and he mentioned that it was not "production grade"..some sort of grey area...

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple example of using angular.js for dependency injection:

```
 function HelloWorld($scope){
     $scope.name="ajay";
  }

HelloWorld.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Comment: above is simple example of dependency injection using angular.js